# R assign along a vector

Tags: r, list, assign

I have an ini-file, read as a list by R (in the example l). Now I want to add further sub-lists along a vector (m) and assign always the same constant to them. My attempt so far:

```
l <- list("A")
m <- letters[1:5]
n <- 5

for (i in 1:5){
  assign(paste0("l$A$",m[i]), n)
}
# which does not work   


# example of the desired outcome:
> l$A$e
[1] 5
```

I don't think that I have fully understood how lists work yet...

Comment: Avoid ever using `assign` in R: `l$A <- setNames(rep(list(n), length(m)), m)`. Simply extend list element with assign operator `<-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
L[["A"]][m] <- n

L$A$e
# [1] 5
```

Data:

```
L <- list(A = list())
m <- letters[1:5]
n <- 5
```

Comment: Just solved it nearly by myself, with the real file where it worked the way you provide, but in the example I did not L <- list(A = list()) (where in the real data the list was areal list^^)